AKS access files on shared managed disk
Ive some trouble mounting a single disk Premium_LRS in Azure Kubernetes (AKS).
In the past I used the FileShare to mount the same volume to different pods so they could access the same drive/folder from within different pods. Now, this is very slow to write and do file operations on so I try to switch to a shared mounted disk but I can not access it in the pods. According to the pods events the disk is mounted but I cant access/write to this disk.
My setup:
First Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xx-import
  namespace: ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xx-import
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xx-import
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xx-import
        image: xxx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8083
            protocol: TCP
        volumeDevices:
          - name: my-data
            devicePath: /dev/xvda
      volumes:
      - name: my-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-pvc

Second Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: yy-import
  namespace: ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: yy-import
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: yy-import
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: yy-import
        image: yyy
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8083
            protocol: TCP
        volumeDevices:
          - name: my-data
            devicePath: /dev/xvda
      volumes:
      - name: my-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-pvc

PVC
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: ns
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: premium_disk_shares
  volumeMode: Block 
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi

StorageClass
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: premium_disk_shares
parameters:
  skuName: Premium_LRS
  maxShares: "2"
  cachingMode: None  #
provisioner: disk.csi.azure.com
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true

When I apply this, i get an ok message for both pods:
SuccessfulMountVolume
Normal
xx-import-558b79994c-m28vg
Pod
MapVolume.MapPodDevice succeeded for volume "pvc-001a4e22-41fb-414e-9e03-e0f561b583b6" globalMapPath "/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/volumeDevices/pvc-001a4e22-41fb-414e-9e03-e0f561b583b6/dev"
12s
SuccessfulMountVolume
Normal
xx-import-558b79994c-m28vg
Pod
MapVolume.MapPodDevice succeeded for volume "pvc-001a4e22-41fb-414e-9e03-e0f561b583b6" volumeMapPath "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/de7bac8d-1585-4e6f-8f23-77ca2a56fb77/volumeDevices/kubernetes.io~csi"

But how can I now write to the disk so I see the files from within pod xx inside pod yy and vice versa? Is this even possible with an SSD drive?
I already checked: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/azuredisk-csi-driver/tree/master/deploy/example/sharedisk
--> Multi-node read write is not supported by common file systems (e.g. ext4, xfs), it's only supported by cluster file systems. --> Is this still the case :) other ideas?
Thanks a lot for your help!

From the opening of the [tag:kubernetes] tag wiki: KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here.

Given your requirement to mount a single disk (Premium_LRS) in AKS and share it across multiple pods, the correct approach would be to use Azure Files for shared read-write access instead of Azure Disks, as Azure Disks do not support multi-node read-write access with common file systems (ext4, xfs).
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azurefiles-premium
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
parameters:
  skuName: Premium_LRS
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: Immediate


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azurefiles-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefiles-premium
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi


Update Deployments to Use Azure Files
xx deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xx-import
  namespace: ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xx-import
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xx-import
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xx-import
        image: xxx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8083
            protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
          - name: my-data
            mountPath: /mnt/data
      volumes:
      - name: my-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: azurefiles-pvc



yy deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: yy-import
  namespace: ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: yy-import
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: yy-import
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: yy-import
        image: yyy
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8083
            protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
          - name: my-data
            mountPath: /mnt/data
      volumes:
      - name: my-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: azurefiles-pvc



you should be able to set up shared storage using Azure Files with your AKS cluster, allowing for multi-node read-write capabilities.
References:

Use Azure Premium SSD v2 disks on Azure Kubernetes Service - Use the persistent volume


Thanks for your response, but as explained in the question, I used file share in the past as solution but its too slow (fe extracting a zip file of 200MB takes 2 hours instead of 10seconds on an SSD)...
